# Why callback in REST API?

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous

Given a REST API with 2 endpoints:

**http://example.com/api/send?id=someId**

Client-side:

> The call to this endpoint, is done asynchrnously in the code.

Server-side:

> Upon receiving the request, a few asynchrnous tasks are started. The
>   server then awaits the result of those asynchronous tasks using the
>   `await` keyword. At last it returns the result.

---

**http://example.com/api/sendAsync?id=someId&callbackUrl=http://something.com/done**

Client-side:

> The call to this endpoint, is done asynchrnously in the code.

Server-side:

> Upon receiving the request, a few asynchrnous tasks are started. The server immediately returns a result with an Id to identify the operation. Whenever the result is available, the server calls the callbackUrl with the result and Id.

Why would I ever need the second approach?

To me it seems that the first approach would be just as good. The fact that the server waits for the result, using the `await` keyword makes it non-blocking, as everything after the keyword is registered as a continuation. Also the client-side is non-blocking, as it's an async web request.

I do realize that the second approach could be useful, if it's a very very long taking requests (+5min). - However, I cant help to feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: The server may be async non blocking, however most clients will timeout around the 30 second mark. So if you have a long running process like maybe AI prediction or training, then you'll want to supply a callback so the service can notify, no matter how long it took.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first approach is fine for `small(er) operations` that don't need to be scaled out on the server side. A very rough example would be something like this:

```cs
public Response SomeApiMethod(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

This is obviously something you can't scale out very well and also a very basic operation which I would put in your first approach.

Now, on the other hand if you provide some functionality that needs to do some `really heavy lifting` on something like a huge DB that simply may take forever then you're better off with the `Callback approach`. Complex operations tend to cause more errors than much simpler operations, which can be handled differently on the server. Like if something goes wrong in a transaction that is part of the callback process the server could simply restart the whole process and still notify the user about the result.

**Something I want to mention about your second approach:**

I assume that you would use `ASP.NET` for your API, and I'm by far no ASP.NET expert but I'm pretty sure that you can't just trigger long-running `Task`s within a Request that already returned a response as they'd simply get `recycled` the sooner or later.

However, what you can do is use some kind of `MessageQueue` (like [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)...) which receives a message about your task which then can be easily handled by a flexible amount of clients. If you need to scale your API to handle a larger amount of users then you just throw more clients that listen for new messages of your Queue at it and you're basically done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) - The API uses a `MessageQueue` (Actor model), which is global and therefore not recycled. - So in short the second approach is only relevant for operations that can take a long time to complete?

Comment: Yes, anything else is overkill and harder to use on the client side. For me as a potential user of your API it's so much easier if I can make a request and then immediately get the response including everything I wanted to know.

Now, if you'd do the request then you'd probably wait a few seconds (or even longer) before you can continue with your own logic if you really depend on the results of your API until you did the Callback. That could make the code much harder to write and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I can see couple more usages:

1) non .net clients can easily use second approach

2) you want to process callback on different URL(common practice in payment system API's)